# How to change the background color of select option's items on hover in react bootstrap

Tags: css, html-select, react-bootstrap

I have tried changing the select option's items background color when the user hover over it. However, I couldn't find a way to fix the problem. My Code

```
    <label>Blood Group</label>
          <select className="custom-select form-control rounded-pill form-input-background" value={bloodGroup} onChange={(e) => setBloodGroup(e.target.value)}>
                <option value='A+'>A+</option>
                <option value='A-'>A-</option>
                <option value='B+'>B+</option>
                <option value='B-'>B-</option>
                <option value='O+'>O+</option>
                <option value='O-'>O-</option>
                <option value='AB+'>AB+</option>
                <option value='AB-'>AB-</option>
         </select>
```

My CSS

```
.form-input-background{
    background-color: #E6E6E6!important;
}
.custom-select option {
    background: #E6E6E6; 
    border-radius: 1em!important;
}
```

Comment: were you able to solve this?